# Hindi-dubbed Japanese show in which they used to swipe cards in their trucks to use different abilities quite similar to "Madan Senki Ryukendo"

Tags: story-identification, tv

I remember back in late 2000s there was this show in which people used to swipe cards to like power up and use different abilities. There was this one episode where a guy created a rainbow from what seemed like a firetruck.  It was quite similar to *Madan Senki Ryukendo*.